# DataDog api - sending a stack trace

Tags: java, newrelic, datadog

Im replacing our existing **NewRelic** java support code with **DataDog** and am wondering about sending error messages. NewRelic has the `.noticeEvent()` call. The [DDog library](https://github.com/DataDog/java-dogstatsd-client) Im using has a `.recordEvent()` but doesn't seem to have a way to send a stack trace.

Anyone been down this road before? I can send text via the above but I need a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the products and libraries that you are using, but there is an open source library **MgntUtils** that can extract full or filtered stacktrace from exception as a String. Since you mentioned that you can pass the text (i.e. String) this library may help you. Here are the links to **MgntUtils** library:

1. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles Detailed article that explains what utilities are available in **MgntUtils** library and how to use them
2. http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmichaelgantman - Here you can get it as Maven resource (also library, source and Javadoc available as a separate resource)
3. Github: https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt - Here you can get this library as a git project as well as Jars for library itself, sources and javadoc (each in separate jar)

I hope this helps